# Tab for specific js script to change the main content height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a script for a specific tab when it is active, my code is just like this. Each Tabs has different sizes, and I want to have that `.content` will change its height on every tabs.

```
<div class="content">
<ul>
<li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="1" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> ... </div>
<div id="2" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> ... </div>
<div id="3" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> ... </div>
<div id="4" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> ... </div>
</div>
```

this is the css of .leftup

```
.leftupt {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'FuturaLTRegular';
    height: auto;
    left: 31px;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 429px;
    width: 360px !important;
}
```

for now this is what it look like..

```
<div id="1" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> ... <script></script> </div>
<div id="2" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> ... <script></script> </div>
<div id="3" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> ... <script></script> </div>
<div id="4" class=".singles"><div class="leftupt">...</div><div class="wrapright"> ...</div> <script></script> </div>
```

my script is like this but it won't work...

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
var biggestHeight = jQuery(".content").height();
jQuery(".leftupt").each(function(){
if (jQuery(this).height() > biggestHeight ) {
    biggestHeight = jQuery(this).height();
}
});
if (jQuery('.leftupt').height == 0){
    biggestHeight=jQuery('.content').height();
}
jQuery(".content").height(biggestHeight);
</script>
```

Is it possible that it can give the `.content` height that is dynamic and not static, if what is the height of the .left, it will also the lenght of the .content?

Comment: I've read this a couple of times and I don't really understand what you want to do. Could you first set up a http://jsfiddle.net/w8Emf/1/ and get it working there. Might help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
  if (jQuery('.leftupt').height == 0)
```

to

```
  if (jQuery('.leftupt').height() == 0)
```